# Angularjs - date/time stamp

Tags: forms, angularjs, datetime

I am trying to figure out something using angularjs. Basically, today I decided to add a time/date stamp in my form. In other words, when someone is trying to post something, the time and date will appear.

Since I have a form with a live preview, I was trying to connect the time on the live preview. Afterwards, the time stamp would get published so that I could orderBy the comments from most recent to less recent.

I have two plunkers. For some reason, I couldn't get the code to properly work. Instead of showing up in the live preview as it should, it doesn't at all. It will on the form though. The first plunker has the bare minimum code, and is shown in the following link, while the second plunker is at the bottom of this message.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zgqXGGpoOw3UY90qT23H?p=catalogue

I will still display a portion of the code here, which is where my problem lies:

```
 <blockquote ng-repeat="review in product.reviews | orderBy:'date'">
                        <b>Date: {{review.date}}</b>
            </blockquote>


           <form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewForm.$valid && reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>

                <blockquote>
                    <b>Date: {{reviewCtrl.review.date}}</b>
                    <br/>
                </blockquote>

<!-- DATE AND TIME -->

            <!-- The other time formats are at the bottom of this page -->
            <div ng-controller="timecontoller" ng-init="init();">
            <div ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.date" ng-repeat="date in dates">
                <b>Date: {{date.date1 | datetime}}</b>
            </div>
            </div>

            </form>
```

While the second plunker has the whole viewable portion so that you can visually see the form (I removed certain elements though to make it easier to see). You'll have to click on the word "Review" first.

http://embed.plnkr.co/hHm1OPHk1uFD6YP2Roju/preview

Comment: The error I see is PanelController is not defined.

Comment: Everything should be defined. I just stripped the whole thing down. In the other link, I have the whole thing for reference. I actually have tabs and everything.

Comment: @tgeery I think I needed add your name to tag you in my response /\/\ Oh btw, if you check out this plunker, you will see what I mean about the date/time not appearing in the live preview :) http://embed.plnkr.co/hHm1OPHk1uFD6YP2Roju/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i followed your code correctly, it seems that you are trying to assign the review date with this line:

```
ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.date"
```

but its really not being given a data model or binding.  If you truly wanted to transfer your timecontroller time update to the reviewController then I would recommend not using that as a controller, but instead refactor it as a service. [Learn more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Of course, you could also just open up your timeController scope and use a click event to transfer the data or something like that, but it doesn't seem like it should really be a controller to begin with.

Now i think I ended up changing your code more than it will really help you at all.  But here is a quick implementation of how it can be done by making your timeController a service.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNZfLMgTC6EepsMsZ83r?p=preview)

Just curious, why do you prefer this to $scope? It was giving me some trouble. Never really dealt with that before.

Comment: I've been playing w/ the code, & I reforked it here http://embed.plnkr.co/5oGffx0UV8jVbbR7aeMN/preview The code works great. Though, I gotta figure out why the output displays the time/date in an ugly fashion lol. As for your question, I'm relatively new to angularjs, & the documentation lacks that teaching depth. I'm doing the best I can with the tools I get my hands on. Some of those are vids, tips/tricks from websites; when I stumble on something I really have trouble dealing w/, I come here, as having a second pair of coding hands can help, after I spent hours of trying to fix my own code.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of space lol. Adding to what I said right above, since I'm relatively new to angularjs, the nuances of using $scope, directives and all those things doesn't speak to me just yet. So, I honestly can't see (or understand at this point) the difference or advantages/disadvantages of using $scope or controllers and so forth. I realize sometimes my code looks less knowledgeable than someone else's code, but this is because I am trying the best that I can while learning, with the tools I get my hands on.

Comment: Found it :D Was missing a pipe + datetime :D Looks fantastic now! Well, minus the CSS which I will work on later lol. tgeery, I would like to thank you for being that second pair of coding hands :)

Comment: Yes, angular is very well thoughtout with all its nuances. There is a lot to learn, but its gets more intuitive with time.  I think for the most part, $scope is the preferred way to implement DOM data-binding. Your code looked pretty good though.  The only thing I'd say is when youre trying to interchange information between controllers, its usually best to think theres a better way.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I just hope that there will be more things available online for angularjs. Right now, everything is either html, css, jquery and tiny bit of php. Of course, as for languages I never studied, I wouldn't know (so many languages out there, but I would like to learn java afterwards). Angularjs is just not out there yet, even though it's been for what, 5 years? I find that to be so shocking, as this is the age of internet, computers, information etc.

Comment: Btw. I think using generators is a great way to learn good practices.  I personally enjoy the angular-fullstack generator if you're in a node environment.

Comment: What is that? I googled it, but the dif websites I looked at didn't explain what it's for.

Comment: Its a generator for new projects, but more so its a generator for adding different Angular & Node MVC/MV** components to your project.  It's very grunt heavy, and may turn out to be a lousy way to learn, but I think its worth the time to create a new project and then walk through the code to make sure you follow the app flow. Try adding subgenerators for services/endpoints/routes and see if you can understand their role in the app.  Unfortunately, it would require a working knowledge of node.  https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-php may be a better choice if you prefer PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna take a look at it once I get the opportunity :)